# Catan robber rules

Tags: catan

The rules state Any player with more than 7 resource cards must chose and discard half of them.  SO, does this mean that anyone with eight or more cards discard half or does it mean that anyone with 7 ore more cards discard half?

Comment: "Seven or more" and "more than seven" are trivially distinct and separate statements.

Answer (score 3):

If x is the number of resource cards in your hand, and x is greater than 7, discard half of them. If x is equal too or less than seven, do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> The rules state Any player **with more than 7 resource cards** must chose
>   and discard half of them. SO, does this mean that anyone with eight or
>   more cards discard half or does it mean that anyone with 7 ore more
>   cards discard half?

You actually answered your own question when you asked the question. As you said:

> The rules state Any player with **> 7** resource cards...

But then, in the very next sentence you asked whether:

> ... anyone with **>= 7** cards discard half?

"`7 or more`" is another way of saying "`greater than or equal to 7`".

Here's how it works:

- If you have 8 cards you must discard 4 and keep 4.
- If you have 9
  cards, you must discard 4 and keep 5 (With an odd number of cards the
  advantage always goes to the player).